# Get the row and column name of the minimum element of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I need to get the row and column name of the smallest element of a matrix

```
> mat = matrix(data=runif(12), nrow = 4, ncol=4)
> rownames(mat) = colnames(mat) = letters[1:4]
> 
> mat
  a         b         c         d
a 0.3167865 0.6958895 0.4233572 0.3167865
b 0.1042599 0.1552235 0.8461520 0.1552235
c 0.6286461 0.9749868 0.2390978 0.6286461
d 0.5923721 0.7823673 0.8427426 0.5923721
> min = min(mat)
> min
> 0.1042599
```

In this example I'd like to get "a" and "b"

Comment: Also: Nested for looping is not feasible because I want to apply it to a lot of huge matrices (dimension > 100)

Answer (score 57):

```
> inds = which(mat == min(mat), arr.ind=TRUE)
> inds
  row col
a   1   2
> rnames = rownames(mat)[inds[,1]]
> cnames = colnames(mat)[inds[,2]]
```

This will give you the row/column names for each entry that equals the minimum value; if you just want the first one, you could only check inds[1,1] and inds[1,2].

Comment: You can also do `inds <- arrayInd(which.min(mat), dim(mat))`.  That'll save you from allocating the result of the `==` and also guarantee a single row.

Comment: Yeah, I knew there was something that would do it in one line...it's not clear to me whether one would more generally want all the matches or just the first, so I guess it's best to present both.

Comment: If a missing observation is present in the `matrix` remember to specify `, na.rm = TRUE` in the `min` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple minimum values, the first two options below only return the row and column index of the first minimum value but the last two options return the row and column index of all minimum values:

```
set.seed(0)
m=matrix(round(runif(1e6,0,1e5)),1e3)

b=microbenchmark(times=100,
  arrayInd(which.min(m),dim(m)),
  {w=which.min(m);c((w-1)%%nrow(m),(w-1)%/%nrow(m))+1},
  which(m==min(m),arr.ind=T),
  {w=which(m==min(m));cbind((w-1)%%nrow(m),(w-1)%/%nrow(m))+1}
)

a=aggregate(b$time,list(gsub(" ","",gsub("     ",";",gsub("\\{    ","{",b$expr)))),median)
a=a[order(a[,2]),]
writeLines(paste(sprintf("%.3f",a[,2]/min(a[,2])),gsub(" ","",a[,1])))
```

Result:

```
1.000 arrayInd(which.min(m),dim(m))
1.002 {w=which.min(m);c((w-1)%%nrow(m),(w-1)%/%nrow(m))+1}
3.183 {w=which(m==min(m));cbind((w-1)%%nrow(m),(w-1)w%/%nrow(m))+1}
3.183 which(m==min(m),arr.ind=T)
```