# Extracting Row and column names of an adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r

```
    library(sna)  
    library(proxy)  
    library(igraph)  
    rawdataframe<-read.csv(file =     "~/Desktop/SNA/Techniques/LinkPrediction/Sample.csv" ,fill=TRUE,header=FALSE,sep=",")  
    rawgraphdata<-    graph.data.frame(rawdataframe,directed=TRUE,vertices=NULL)  
    adj<-get.adjacency(rawgraphdata)  
    g1<-as.matrix(adj)  
    adjmatrix<-simil(g1, method ="Jaccard", diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE ,pairwise = TRUE, by_rows = TRUE, convert_distances = TRUE,     auto_convert_data_frames = TRUE)  
    adjmatrix[adjmatrix >= 0.75]<-1   
    adjmatrix[adjmatrix <= 0.75]<-0
```

I have used simil proxy measure and the result obtained as below.

the output is as below:

```
       2 159 3 5 858 100 114 171
   2   0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0
   159 0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0
   3   0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0
   5   0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0
   858 0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0
   100 0   0 0 0   0   0   1   1
   114 0   0 0 0   0   1   0   1
   171 0   0 0 0   0   1   1   0
```

I want to extract (row, column) pair where value corresponds to 1.

Comment: try this `which(adjmatrix==1,arr.ind=T)`

Comment: It is returning 26 27 28. I tried other arguments such as rbind and cbind. However, the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by NicE, you could use `which` with `arr.ind=1` which gives you the row and column indices; 
Collect the row and column names for example with `apply`:

```
> apply(which (as.matrix(adjmatrix)==1,arr.ind=T), 2, function(x)rownames(as.matrix(adjmatrix))[x])

     row   col  
[1,] "114" "100"
[2,] "171" "100"
[3,] "100" "114"
[4,] "171" "114"
[5,] "100" "171"
[6,] "114" "171"
```

which will work in your case because in an adjacency matrix row and column names should be the same.

Comment: see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207833/get-the-row-and-column-name-of-the-minimum-element-of-a-matrix

Comment: Error in arr.ind && !is.null(d <- dim(x)) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'  - I am unable to comprehend this error when I use the command you suggested.

Comment: Could you post what comes out of  `dput(adjmatrix)` to make sure the objects are similar?  If I read the example matrix from your question, it works fine for me.

Comment: dput(adjmatrix)
`structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), Size = 8L, Labels = c("2", 
"159", "3", "5", "858", "100", "114", "171"), class = c("simil", 
"dist"), Diag = TRUE, Upper = TRUE, method = "Jaccard", call = dist(x = x, 
    y = y, method = method, diag = diag, upper = upper, pairwise = pairwise, 
    by_rows = by_rows, convert_similarities = FALSE, auto_convert_data_frames = auto_convert_data_frames))  `

Comment: `This is the output of the mentioned arguments`

Comment: user1981275 `Could let me know the command to read the example matrix`

Comment: I used `read.table` with `text` argument and pasted your matrix. I see that your matrix is of both, class `simil` and `dist`, so you could convert it using `as.matrix`, see updated example above. Does this work?

Comment: `What does x denote in function(x)`

Comment: Have a look at `?apply`: Each column of the matrix gets passed to the anonymous function with argument `x`, so `x` is a vector in this case.