# What is the opposite function of max.col (R language)

Tags: r

What is the opposite function of `max.col` (R language).

I couldn't find `min.col` or relevant info in the manual:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/maxCol.html

I'm trying to generate an opposite function of this:

```
cols = which(names(df) %in% c( "avp", "USD.KRW","cd")); 
df$max_col = names(df)[cols][max.col(df[cols])]
```

Comment: Must be something close to `which.min` but not sure. Try `apply(df,1,which.min)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the row and column name of the minimum element of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207833/get-the-row-and-column-name-of-the-minimum-element-of-a-matrix)

Comment: What is `cols` in your example? @Renaissance please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: cols = which(names(df) %in% c( "avp", "USD.KRW","cd")); 
df$max_col = names(df)[cols][max.col(df[cols])]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```r
min.col <- function(m, ...) max.col(-m, ...)
```

Used in formal optimization (where many tools prefer to find a *minimum* of a function), the opposite of a maximal number is the minimal negative number.

Comment: Renaissance, does this answer your question? If yes, please "accept" it. If not, I suggest you edit your question, otherwise you are less likely to get a better answer.