# Invalid subscript type 'list' error and comparing distance between points across two data frames

Tags: r, data.table, spatial

I have two dataframes that store point data. One contains 6 points (df1.sf) and the other has 20,000+ points (df2.sf). I want to calculate the distance between each of the points in df2 and each of the points in df1 (one to many, repeated six times), and then generate some kind of output that indicates which of the 6 points from df1 is closest to each point of df2. This is what I've got so far:

```
dist <- function(a){
                 dt <- data.table(as.numeric(sf::st_distance(df1.sf$borderpoints, a)))
                 return(which.min(dt$V1))}
results <- df2.sf[, j = list(Closest =  dist(df2.sf)), by = 1:nrow(df2.sf)]

Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

But this keeps giving me 'Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list''. I'm very new to R so suspect I'm doing something wrong - would really appreciate any tips, either of how to fix the code below or if there's a better way to approach things.

Comment: Welcome to R and stack overflow!  I'd suggest you post the contents of df1.sf and maybe the first 10 records in df2 so we can see how your data are structured.  It's hard to read the code without seeing the data in the dataframe.  Here are some tips to create a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  You'll also want to include a minimum data set so that folks can run the code to help debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both frames have a `$geometry` column that is `"sfc"` class <sup>1</sup>, we can simply call `sf::st_length` on both frames.

I'm assuming a lot about your data, I'll generate some with

```r
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
df1.sf <- data.table(id = 1:6, geometry = sf::st_sfc(sf::st_coordinates(nc)[1:6,1:2] |> apply(1, sf::st_point, simplify=FALSE)))
df2.sf <- data.table(id = 7:20, geometry = sf::st_sfc(sf::st_coordinates(nc)[7:20,1:2] |> apply(1, sf::st_point, simplify=FALSE)))
df1.sf
#       id               geometry
#    <int>            <sfc_POINT>
# 1:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
# 2:     2 POINT (-81.541 36.273)
# 3:     3 POINT (-81.562 36.274)
# 4:     4 POINT (-81.633 36.341)
# 5:     5 POINT (-81.741 36.392)
# 6:     6 POINT (-81.698 36.472)
```

and similar for `df2.sf`.

With this, we can simply do

```r
dists <- t(sf::st_distance(df1.sf$geometry, df2.sf$geometry))
dists
#          [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]     [,6]
#  [1,] 0.36624 0.29522 0.28323 0.19178 0.13318 0.047776
#  [2,] 0.40637 0.34243 0.33400 0.25169 0.21024 0.121216
#  [3,] 0.36171 0.35840 0.36948 0.36975 0.43523 0.367171
#  [4,] 0.32837 0.32834 0.34037 0.34702 0.41979 0.356919
#  [5,] 0.31610 0.32380 0.33750 0.35351 0.43378 0.375848
#  [6,] 0.29343 0.30839 0.32361 0.34905 0.43689 0.385060
#  [7,] 0.28948 0.32021 0.33799 0.37931 0.47701 0.433426
#  [8,] 0.27055 0.30798 0.32675 0.37578 0.47842 0.440525
#  [9,] 0.27367 0.31862 0.33827 0.39428 0.50053 0.466816
# [10,] 0.26719 0.31495 0.33491 0.39395 0.50188 0.470579
# [11,] 0.23961 0.28791 0.30799 0.36901 0.47845 0.450151
# [12,] 0.19325 0.23056 0.24973 0.30492 0.41305 0.384832
# [13,] 0.16285 0.19676 0.21581 0.27198 0.38166 0.357178
# [14,] 0.14974 0.18736 0.20692 0.26738 0.37907 0.358095
```

where the columns represent `df1.sf` points, and the rows correspond to rows of `df2.sf`. We can find the min-distance by using `max.col` on the negative distances (there is no `min.col`, [What is the opposite function of max.col (R language)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54730622/3358272)), returning the *index* (column) for each row:

```r
max.col(-dists)
#  [1] 6 6 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If you need the actual minimum distance, you can use

```r
dists[cbind(1:nrow(dists), max.col(-dists))]
#  [1] 0.047776 0.121216 0.358401 0.328337 0.316101 0.293432 0.289480 0.270551 0.273672 0.267187 0.239613 0.193251
# [13] 0.162851 0.149745
```

If you the coordinates of the corresponding rows, then

```r
df1.sf[max.col(-dists),]
#        id               geometry
#     <int>            <sfc_POINT>
#  1:     6 POINT (-81.698 36.472)
#  2:     6 POINT (-81.698 36.472)
#  3:     2 POINT (-81.541 36.273)
#  4:     2 POINT (-81.541 36.273)
#  5:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
#  6:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
#  7:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
#  8:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
#  9:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
# 10:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
# 11:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
# 12:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
# 13:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
# 14:     1 POINT (-81.473 36.234)
```

Note that none of this actually required or used the `data.table` aspect of these objects.

---

Notes:

- <sup>1</sup>: One reason I assume `"sfc"`-classed `$geometry` column is that you have tagged the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) tag and appear to be using its semantics in your code. If you have frames that are of class `"sf"`, then `data.table` semantics will not work, so your code would have erred quickly and differently. When I want to work with `sf`-infused objects but still use `data.table` semantics, this is how I tend to work.

  This may work just as easily, directly or with minimal change, if your objects are `"sf"`-classed frames, with or without `data.table` somewhere underneath it all.