# Plotting function with 3 parameters (4d) in R

Tags: r, 4d

I want to see how three variables x, y, and z respond to a function f using R.

I've searched for R solutions (e.g. rgl using 4d plots) but none seem to allow the input of a function as the fourth variable while allowing manipulation of x, y, and z across their full range of values.

```
# First I create three variables that each have a domain 0 to 4
x 
y 
z 

# Then I create a function from those three variables
f <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
```

EDIT: I originally stated that I wanted x, y, and z to be seq(0, 4, 0.01) but in fact I only want them to range from 0 to 4, and do so independently of other variables. In other words, I want to plot the function across a range of values letting x move independently of y and z and so forth, rather than plotting a 3-D line. The result should be a 3-D surface.

I want to:
a) see how the function f responds to all possible combinations of x, y, and z across a range of x, y, and z values 0 to 4, and 
b) find what maxima/minima exist especially when holding one variable constant.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're looking for, but does the following work? `plot3D::scatter3D(x, y, z, f)`

Comment: It does work for my original question but I just updated the answer as I realized, thanks to you and @Chelmy88, that I had posed the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a mathematical questions. Unfortunately, our computer screens are not really made fro 4D, neither our brains. So what you ask wont be possible as if. Indeed, you want to show a dense set of data (a cube between 0 and 4), and we can not display what is "inside" the cube.

To come back to R, you can always display a slice of it, for example fixing `z` and plot `sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)` for `x` and `y`. Here you have two examples:

```
# Points where the function should be evaluated
x <- seq(0, 4, 0.01)
y <- seq(0, 4, 0.01)
z <- seq(0, 4, 0.01)

# Compute the distance from origin
distance <- function(x,y,z) {
  sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
}

# Matrix to store the results
slice=matrix(0, nrow=length(x),ncol=length(y))
# Fill the matrix with a slice at z=3
i=1
for (y_val in y)
{
  slice[,i]=distance(x,y_val,3)
  i=i+1
}

# PLot with plot3D library
require(plot3D)
persp3D(z = slice, theta = 100,phi=50)

# PLot with raster library
library(raster)
plot(raster(slice,xmn=min(x), xmx=max(x), ymn=min(y), ymx=max(y)))
```

If you change your `z` values, you will not really change the shape (just making it "flatter" for bigger `z`). Note that the function being symmetric in `x`, `y` and `z`, the same plots are produced if you keep `x`or `y` constant.

For your last question about the maximum, you can re-use the `slice` matrix and do:

```
max_ind=which(slice==max(slice),arr.ind = TRUE)
x[max_ind[,1]]
y[max_ind[,2]]
```

(see [Get the row and column name of the minimum element of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207833/get-the-row-and-column-name-of-the-minimum-element-of-a-matrix))

But again with math we can see from your equation that the maximum will always be obtained by maxing `x`, `y` and `z`. Indeed, the function simply measure the distance from the origin.